# Ring multiplication algorithms?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algorithms, arithmetic, computational-complexity, unique-factorization-domains

Consider Gauss result :

Gauss's complex multiplication algorithm

Complex multiplication normally involves four multiplications and two additions.

By 1805 Gauss had discovered a way of reducing the number of multiplications to three.

The product$ (a + bi) · (c + di) $can be calculated in the following way.

$k1 = c · (a + b)$

$k2 = a · (d − c)$

$k3 = b · (c + d)$

Real part $= k1 − k3$

Imaginary part $ = k1 + k2.$
This algorithm uses only three multiplications, rather than four, and five additions or subtractions rather than two. If a multiply is more expensive than three adds or subtracts, as when calculating by hand, then there is a gain in speed. On modern computers a multiply and an add can take about the same time so there may be no speed gain.

Now the natural questions :

1) How to extend these results to other abelian rings ?

2) How to prove that the number of multiplications is the lowest possible for a given abelian ring ?

3) how many methods are there for a given abelian ring ?

And perhaps a weird one

4) is it possible to INCREASE the number of multiplications ? ( say an algoritm that uses 5 products for complex number multiplication ).

*** edit ***

5) is this related to the property of Unique factorization ( or non-Unique factorization ) of the considered ring ??

This question is dedicated to my teacher tommy1729.

Comment: Complex multiplication might be a bad tag ...

Comment: A few comments. 1) Because multiplication (of for example large integers) is more expensive than addition even on modern computers, the same idea (less multiplications, more additions/substractions) can be used to reduce the computational complexity of integer multiplication. Read about [Karatsuba's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm). 2) I have seen similar ideas used in reducing the cost of multiplication in finite fields and polynomial rings. 3) Yes, complex-multiplication is not a good tag here :-)

Comment: I think you might be interested in the content of (e.g.) [these slides](http://web.math.unifi.it/users/ottavian/colloquium_kias.pdf), which are about fast matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Jyrki i was aware of Karatsuba's work. And those other things. Well a bit at least , I am no expert. It is Nice. But i see no ( deep ) connection/solution from these ideas to the answers desired in the OP.

Comment: I assume that when the degree of extension is an odd A , and A = B p for a prime p then , define f(x) as the function giving the least amount of products needed for degree x , we have f(A) = f(B) f(p).  In other words : conjecture : the number of products needed is a multiplicative function of the odd degree.